# Not able to scrape location using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

i am newbie to python data scraping and trying to scrape data from kickstarter.
i am using the following code to scrape location data from

[link](https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?term=security&sort=magic&seed=2425842&page=1)

i am using the following code

```
test_page=requests.get('https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?term=security&sort=magic&seed=2425842&page=1')    
test_pagetree= html.fromstring(test_page.content)
test_loc= test_pagetree.xpath('//[@id="projects_list"]/li/div/div/div/a/span')[0].text
```

and getting a 'list index out of range' error.

I am using the google chrome to inspect and get the xpath for the element above.

Comment: What piece of data were you trying to extract from the page?

Comment: Just maybe, with chrome, you are connected, or with chrome, the result of this page is not the same as with python get (User-Agent, User-Language, .... fill by browser but not by you). I try with chrome, no xpath for the element above for me.

Comment: I am trying to extract the location which would be Brooklyn, NY for the first listing, Kiel Germany for the second and so on..

Comment: @allonhadaya... i am trying to extract Brooklyn,NY

Comment: @A.H..What would be the path to be used for extracting Brooklyn,NY

Answer (score 0):

The location elements can be selected using the `location-name` class like so:

```
...
test_loc = test_pagetree.find_class('location-name')[0].text
```