# Not able to extract data from tabs using python path

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

hi i am trying to extract data from a tab in a page

the page is 
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1311034023/priva-the-invincible-and-reusable-camera-privacy-s/description

and i am trying to extract the location

Brooklyn, NY

i am using the following python code along with path(using google chrome inspect).

```
test_page= requests.get('https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1311034023/priva-the-invincible-and-reusable-camera-privacy-s/description')
test_pagetree= html.fromstring(test_page.content)

testxpath= test_pagetree.xpath('//*[@id="content-wrap"]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/a[1]/text()')
print testxpath
```

Comment: How is this question different than your [last one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402310/not-able-to-scrap-location-using-python)?

Comment: @kjhughes: Different URL and XPath expression. Krishna, if your previous question is not longer valid, please close/delete it. For this question, you told us what you tried and what result you wanted; please also tell what result you actually got and how that differed from what you wanted.

Comment: Ok, and to add to your recommendations, both questions should be self-contained, not dependent upon external links which may change or go away over time.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
testxpath = test_pagetree.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "ksr-icon__location")]/following-sibling::text()[1]')
```

In other words, find the `span` element(s) with the `class` attribute whose value contains `"ksr-icon__location"`, and extract the following text node.

This will return two text nodes, each containing `Brooklyn, NY`. Pick the first one:

```
print testxpath[0].text
```

You can't just tell your browser "give me the XPath of this element" and assume that XPath expression will always work. For example, the HTML structure shown in the browser may be modified from the HTML that was fetched from the server (and fetched by the web scraping program).

XPath can usually overcome those possible differences, *if you know how to use it.* But it's a powerful and complex tool, a complete query language. If you're going to do web-scraping, it's worthwhile to learn how XPath works (or some other tool, and use that).